# Expression Must Be Modifiable Value (C)

Tags: c, loops, expression, unmodifiable

Quick question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int divisor, counter, binary, counter2;
    int digit0, digit1, digit2, digit3; 
    float decimal;

    printf("Decimal\t\tBinary\n");

    for (counter = 0; counter <= 15; counter++) {
        printf("%d\t\n", counter);   

        decimal = counter;

        for (counter2 = 0; counter2 <= 3; counter2++) {
            decimal % 2 == 1 ? digit0 = 1 : digit0 = 0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the error that the "expression must be a modifiable value" on variable name "decimal" in the second for loop.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: `decimal % 2 == 1 ? digit0 = 1 : digit0 = 0)` --> `digit0 = (decimal % 2 == 1 ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Um. `decimal` is `float` ? DId someone add modulo as an allowable binary op to floats while I wasn't paying attention? `fmod` anyone?

Comment: @WhozCraig no... there are multiple problems here

Comment: @M.M Yeah, thought so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `decimal` is `float`,but `%` only for integers.If you really want to mod by using `float`, you can use function `float fmod(float x, float y)`, it calculates `x%y`, and you should include `#include <math.h>` to use it.